# why is keras installed correctly in one terminal session but in all subsequent sessions and my jupyter notebook it says it's not installed?

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new to jupyter notebooks and am trying to run one that imports keras. I found an online tutorial and installed it. In that terminal session, I can succesfully execute the command "import keras". In all subsequent sessions, however, that same command returns that the module isn't found. The same thing happens when I try to run my jupyter notebook.

I tried to just run the notebook from the working session, but it said jupyter wasn't found (it is in every other terminal session.) I reinstalled jupyter in that session and that let me open the notebook, but then it said I didn't have pandas which I definitely do because it comes with anaconda which I'm using.

Working session:

```
(tf) users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

Not working session:

```
(base) users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ python 
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

I see that they're using different versions of python, but I can't even figure out how to get to python 3.6 in my other sessions. Any help would be extremely appreciated-- I'm very lost.

Comment: Did you create virtual environment?

Comment: What does that mean? I'm sorry I'm very new

Comment: Yes i know, i was new too.I mean how did you installed tf -> (tf) users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ python

Comment: ```conda create -n tf python=3.7

conda activate tf

conda install keras``` (sorry it's not letting me have line breaks)

Comment: Then you have to execute `conda activate tf` (in your new session) in order to activate the environment.

Comment: So the (base) doesn't have keras because you have installed it to tf environment.

Comment: That worked! follow up question: now it's saying I don't have pandas installed which I thought came with anaconda and I've definitely used before. Do I have to reinstall it? To clarify it wasn't throwing this error before just the no keras

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you created a virtual environment. That way your Python environment is isolated and you can use different Python versions with different packages for different projects.

Probably you created your environment with something like that, where `env_name` is the name of your environement?

```
conda create -n env_name anaconda
```

In this case you can activate your environment with this command:

```
source activate env_name
```

Comment: That returns ```-bash: activate: No such file or directory```

Comment: Try `conda activate tf`